# one button click creates two events

Tags: c#, database, connection, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I need to create a button that makes two events and saves it into database (arrival and departure time of employee).

**What i need to do** First click on button saves arrival time of employee to database, Second click on **same button** saves departure time of employee (instead of having 2 buttons ofcourse)

I think i need some kind of counter that counts button clicks, or something like that, but i really have no clue how to program sth like that, so if you could please help me out.

**This is what i have so far** Please notice that the code does not work, so there is no problem except for me not knowing how to program it. Thank you

```
int counter = 0;
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        try
        {
            if (counter == 1)
            {

                OleDbConnection myConnection= new OleDbConnection("\\CONNECTION PATH");
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = myConnection;
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Weekdays (Arrival)" + "values(@Arrival)";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Arrival", DateTime.Now);

                myConnection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Arrival added.");
                myConnection.Close();

            }
            else if (counter == 2)
            {
                OleDbConnection myConnection= new OleDbConnection("\\CONNECTION PATH");
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = myConnection;
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Weekdays (Departure)" + "values(@Departure)";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Departure", DateTime.Now);

                myConnection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Departure added.");
                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, it works. Twice, to be exact; until counter becomes 3. I would go with Grant's answer, but additionally also change the text of the button (like alternating between "Arrival and "Departure", or something) to emphasize its current function and avoid confusion.

Comment: @elgonzo It gives me **Data type mismatch in criteria expression.** error for  ---> cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ...something wrong with datetime.now?

Comment: @GrantWinney both are **Date/Time**

Comment: @fkr, sorry i didn't looked at your entire code. My comment was meant specifically regarding your logic for toggling the button function, not about your code handling the database. Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: @GrantWinney it works now, but it sets date under two different ID's...and the date sets as 1990 lol -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a bool to indicate whether the employee is clocked in yet or not.

```
bool clockedIn = false;

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!clockedIn)
    {
        // employee just arrived - log arrival time
    }
    else
    {
        // employee leaving - log departure time
    }

    clockedIn = !clockedIn;
}
```

Comment: It probably works fine, but it gives me **Data type mismatch in criteria expression**. error for ---> cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ...something wrong with datetime.now?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty way:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Tag == null)
        {
            button1.Tag = "toogled";

            // run event 1
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Tag = null;

            // run event 2
        }
    }
```

Comment: It gives me **Data type mismatch in criteria expression.** error for  ---> cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ...something wrong with datetime.now?